# Need some help installing SVN through bash

Tags: bash, svn

I'm trying to setup subversion on my server. I'm logging into my server as root, and I have no idea how to do that.

I was trying to follow this guide:
http://blog.loadbalancer.org/how-to-setup-subversion/

but I can't see a "home" directory. Here are the directories I see instead:

```
./              .bashrc       .login   .spamassassin/  public_html/
../             .cpanel/      .logout  .tcshrc         tmp/
.MirrorSearch/  .cpobjcache/  .my.cnf  bin/
.bash_logout    .cshrc        .pearrc  cpanel3-skel/
.bash_profile   .gnupg/       .rnd     public_ftp/
```

Do I need to create the "home" directory"? or is it called a different name in my server or something?

Appreciate your help

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/118258) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed the steps in that guide and created a user called "svn" (step 2) and logged in as "svn" (step 3) your current working directory should be `/home/svn`. You can confirm this with:

```
pwd
```

If you haven't created the new user yet, though, this command might be suitable:

```
sudo adduser --system --group svn
```

Creating the new user should have automatically created the directory.

The rest of step 3 puts you in the correct directory. Quoting from the guide:

```
$ cd /home/svn
$ mkdir repositories
$ cd repositories
... more instructions ...
```

**Edit**: Note that the instructions don't say create a directory called "svn" - it says make a directory called "repositories" ***in*** `/home/svn`.

Comment: +1 as it maybe the answer the poster is looking for